# IOS10 - Sharing photos - Mail option disappears when 6 photos is selected

Tags: email, sharing, photos.app, ios

I have 1 phone where the mail option disappears when 5-6 photos are selected for sharing

What I do
1. Open the photos app
2. Press Select in top right corner and select one photo
3. Press Share in the bottom left corner
Here I among other options have the the option for sharing via mail
4. Add photos by selecting them in the top 
When I have selected 5 or 6 photos, the mail option disappears.

Is it possible to set a restriction somewhere, that I can remove, or is it size of the photos.

I have another phone with the same setup, but different mail address, on the same domain though, and on this it doesn't happen.

Comment: Are both phones iPhones running iOS 10?

Comment: Yep both using ios10 and both iphone 6

Comment: Using the default mail client or 3rd party app?

Comment: the default mail app under sharing options